# How to add some php function inside html content

Tags: php, html

is it possible to do some function inside html content ?

here my code :

```
$parts = explode(',', 'option 1,option 2,option 3');
echo "<div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
          <label>label</label>
          <select class='form-control' style='width: 100%;' name='select' placeholder='select'>
          foreach($parts as $index=>$key) {
              echo '<option>'.$key .'</option>';
          }
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>";
```

Comment: yes, just part then different.

Comment: i got error undefined variable . i think because of my variable still considered as html content. how do i split it ?@FrayneKonok

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me if anything wrong or not.

Comment: It actually works the other way around. You are adding HTML to PHP coding. Without naming your file some-title.php no code will be parsed/executed. @FrayneKonok answer is correct but won't work if your file is named some-title.html

Comment: @IbnuHabibie, Did you choose the right answer??? If you think that is good for you than its okey.

Comment: thanks for helping @FrayneKonok. but i think i choose the right one for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work, you should do like this :

```
    $parts = explode(',', 'option 1,option 2,option 3');
    echo "<div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <label>label</label>
        <select class='form-control' style='width: 100%;' name='select' placeholder='select'>";
    foreach($parts as $index=>$key) {
        echo '<option>'.$key .'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select></div></div>";
```

Answer (score 8):

Do this think like this way:

Depart the HTML and PHP, use the PHP tag each time when you need inside a HTML page / PHP page.

```
<?php
$parts = explode(',', 'option 1,option 2,option 3');
?>
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <label>label</label>
        <select class='form-control' style='width: 100%;' name='select' placeholder='select'>
        <?php
        foreach($parts as $index=>$key){
        ?>
            <option><?php echo $key;?></option>
        <?php }?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```